# MultipartFile value is coming as null in Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data, multipart

I am consuming a third-party rest endpoint (B)  from my application A. It is working as expected. I am using the below code to call B from A

```
public static String invokeB(String requestJson) throws Exception
{
String response;
byte[] fileContent = requestJson.getBytes();
WebClient myClient = someLogic;

HttpHeaders parts = new HttpHeaders();
parts.setConetentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

ByteArrayResource byteArrayResource = new ByteArrayResource(fileContent);
final HttpEntity<ByteArrayResource> partsEntity = new HttpEntity<>(byteArrayResource, parts);

MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<?>> requestMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
requestMap.add(“datafile”, partsEntity);

response = myClient.post().contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, “”).body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(requestMap)).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
return response;
}
```

Now I am trying to mimic the third-party REST endpoint for some testing. Let’s call it C. When I try to access C from A. The request is coming to C but the request body MultipartFile is coming as null. I cannot make any changes in A or B. I can make code changes only in C.

**My C Controller.**

```
@RestController
public class WrapperController {

@PostMapping(value = “/test”)
public String visionPlusTester(@RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String authorization,
    @RequestBody(required = true) MultipartFile datafile,
    @RequestParam(value = “port”, defaultValue = “1234”, required = false) String port,
    @RequestParam(value = “url”, defaultValue = “10.10.10.10”, required = false) String url) {

    byte[] fileContent = datafile.getBytes();
           return “some JSON String”
}
```

In Application.java I tried adding MultipartResolver

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}
```

In the parameter, I changed @RequestBody with @RequestPart but with the setup, the request did not come to C. It is working perfectly when I test from POSTMAN.
I am using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.11

Also added spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true.  None of them worked. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Going by [this `spring.io` guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/), the `MultipartFile` should also be a `RequestParam`.

Comment: "*Now I am trying to mimic the third-party REST endpoint for some testing...*" - There are dedicated tools for this, e.g. [WireMock (`wiremock.org`)](https://wiremock.org/), [Citrus Integration Testing Framework (`citrusframework.org`)](https://citrusframework.org/) and [Mockoon (`mockoon.com`)](https://mockoon.com/).

Comment: I am already using WireMock for testing locally. The third part REST endpoint is not accessible from the local machine. WireMock mock response is static. I need a dynamic response. So I am writing a wrapper around a third-party REST endpoint and deploying the same in PCF. I've access to PCF from the local machine and PCF has access to the third-party REST endpoint.

Comment: When I use RequestParam the request itself is not coming to the controller.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. [This (`github.com`)](https://github.com/turing85/spring-file-upload/blob/main/src/main/java/de/turing85/spring/fileupload/UploadResource.java) seems to work fine.

Comment: You are seindg `TEXT/PLAIN` remove that header, the `MultipartFile` needs to be a `@RequestPart` or `@RequestParam` but not an `@RequestBody`. Also `datafile` and `dataFile` don't match so the parameters won't be resolved.

Comment: Thank you. but it did not work datafile and dataFile is a typo. I have datafile in all the places in code. Also I tried removing TEXT/PLAIN.  I cannot change the MultipartFile from request body to RequestPart. I do not have any control on third part implementation. When I changed it to @RequestPart I got the following exception "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'datafile' is not present]"

Answer (score 0):

Replaced

```
@RequestBody(required = true) MultipartFile datafile
```

with

```
@RequestParam(required = true) MultivalueMap<String, ByteArrayResource> datafile
```

to make it work

**Working Code**

```
@RestController
public class WrapperController {

@PostMapping(value = “/test”)
public String visionPlusTester(@RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String authorization,
    @RequestParam(required = true) MultivalueMap<String, ByteArrayResource> datafile,
    @RequestParam(value = “port”, defaultValue = “1234”, required = false) String port,
    @RequestParam(value = “url”, defaultValue = “10.10.10.10”, required = false) String url) {

    String fileContent = String.valueOf(datafile.get("datafile"));
           return fileContent
}
```